# Can I manipulate my array to print out one for index start point?

Tags: java, arrays

Can I manipulate my array to print out one for index start point?

My array index starts at 0  and that is fine but I want it to look like it starts at 1 on my output. Is there a way to do this? Here are my for loops:

```
for( x=0;x<3;x++) {
  for( i=0;i<4;i++) {
    if(rounded[i][x]<395 || rounded[i][x] >405) {
        System.out.println("there is an error with point "+i+"on element"+x+"as the temperature is at"+rounded[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("there is an error with point "+(i+1)+"on...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't simply add 1 at the output?

```
 for( x=0;x<3;x++)
 {
    for( i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(rounded[i][x]<395 || rounded[i][x] >405)
        {
            System.out.println("there is an error with point "+(i+1)+"on element"+x+"as the temperature is at"+rounded[i][x]);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: im getting an out of bounds error and its not returning all my test conditions

Comment: @user3188481 then it doesn't work for when you don't add one to the output as well. This works just as well as the original version; the output is just 1 more.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one to both of your loop counters for display purposes, for example -

```
for( x=0;x<3;x++) {
  for( i=0;i<4;i++) {
    if(rounded[i][x]<395 || rounded[i][x] >405) {
        System.out.println("there is an error with point "
            + (1+i) + " on element " + (1+x) 
            + " as the temperature is at " + rounded[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3188481 Did you miss any of the parens? Your `i` and `x` are int(s) correct?